# Warehouse stock restriction not working in edit mode odoo10?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In my custom module I use stock picking type to see the warehouse operations of the user.

```py
class ResUsers(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    default_picking_type_ids = fields.Many2many(
    'stock.picking.type', 'stock_picking_type_users_rel',
    'user_id', 'picking_type_id', string='Warehouse Operations')
```

I added this in user form.

In my sexurity.xml file add

```xml
<record id="filter_user_stock_picking_type" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Filter Stock Picking Type</field>
        <field name="model_id" search="[('model','=','stock.picking.type')]" model="ir.model"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
        <field name="domain_force">[('id','in', [ s.id for s in user.default_picking_type_ids ])]</field>
 </record>
```

so it is worked in when **a user is created and assigns stock operation.**

But when **changed the  stock operation** to particular user, it will not affect.

How to resolve this issue??

Comment: You can try `('id','in', user.default_picking_type_ids.ids)`

Comment: I try that but still not working.It is not working when edit the warehouse operation.It only work when 1st create the operations

Comment: Two things: 1. Did you test it with the admin account? 2. Did you logout and login again after change?

Comment: yes, I checked both but not working.When I use admin account it will affect on operations that firstly create could not be changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the problem is the `Odoo Cache`.
The old values are stored in the Cache for a long time and your change will not take any effect.

You can try it to clear the cache. It helped me to solve the similar problem.

```py
class User(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    @api.multi
    def write(self, vals):
        ret = super(User, self).write(vals)

        if 'default_picking_type_ids' in vals:
            # clear default ir values when default_picking_type_ids changes
            self.env['ir.values'].get_defaults_dict.clear_cache(self.env['ir.values'])
        return ret
```